# Xcode UITableView image does not align properly on simulator

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, alignment, tableview

I am working on a project on Xcode7.3 using swift using autolayout. I am stuck with an problem with the UITableview not displaying properly on the simulator.

I created a ViewController and dragged a TableView into ViewController. Then I dragged a UIView and UIImage ontop of that TableView (To display as a header image). I also dragged a UIImage onto the prototype cell. They are all aligned in the center horizontally and vertically. However, when I run the app, they don't show in the middle of the screen.

[image: UITableView_Problem]

As shown in the UITableView_Problem Image, the images are offset to the right. What is also weird is that when I rotate the screen, the scrollbar on the right does not go all the way to the right. The images appears to be in the center of the screen if I consider where the scroll bar is the end of the screen. But that doesnt make sense because the bottom bar items spans the full width of the screen.

[image: RotatedScreen]

However, if I create a UITableViewController from the story board instead of dragging a TableView onto a ViewController, I do not have a problem at all. (Image3)

It is frustrating because I wanted to add a text field for keyboard at the bottom of the screen just like the comment section in Instagram app. And after hours of searching, it appears that the only way to do that is to drag a tableView onto a ViewController. i stack imgur com JC5Pw png

Could anyone please assist? Much appreciated

> Blockquote

note: I dont have a developers account yet so I cant check on an actual device

Comment: i.stack.imgur.com/JC5Pw.png is the working version if I use only tableView with ViewController rather then UITableViewController.  I have also tried resetting the simulator or changing the simulator device

Comment: What constraints did you add to the tableview?

Answer (score 1):

You are designing your interface in the wRegular/hRegular (or universal) size class. You will need to be very good about your constraints or develop a layout for the wCompact/hRegular size class for iPhones in portrait mode. You can change this by selecting here the blue part on the bottom of your storyboard

[image]

Comment: Sounds good. If you've figured it out make sure you accept an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Dan for your prompt response! I added constraints to everything except for the tableView. Dont know what I was thinking as I have been troubled by this bug for a few days. Everything works fine after the tableView constraints was set!